# Why is this trigger updating when its value is false?

Tags: wpf, triggers, controltemplate

Currently I'm experimenting with a ControlTemplate that has a `ListBox` and an overlapping `Popup` that should trigger once I hover the mouse over the `ListBox`. Now that works well as in the `Popup` displays as soon as I hover over the `ListBox`.

However, as soon as I leave the the `ListBox` like hover over the `Popup` the Trigger seems to update the `IsOpen`-Property again and closes the `Popup`. From my understanding, the trigger should only fire when the `IsMouseOver`-Property is set to `true` and thus the `Popup` should stay open (Which is what I intend because it shall contain clickable elements).

Do I have a logical error or how exactly does the trigger work in this case?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectTargetsListBox">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="PART_ListBoxBonusTargets" Height="200"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Targets}" />
        <Popup Name="PART_PopupListBoxBonusTargets" 
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_ListBoxBonusTargets}" 
               Placement="Right" 
               VerticalOffset="-10" HorizontalOffset="-10" 
               PopupAnimation="Fade" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="True">
            <Border MinHeight="300" MinWidth="400" 
                    Background="{StaticResource BonusPopupBackgroundColor}" 
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource BonusForegroundColor}" 
                    BorderThickness="3">
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger SourceName="PART_ListBoxBonusTargets" 
                 Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_PopupListBoxBonusTargets" 
                    Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have a logical error or how exactly does the trigger work in this case?

The IsOpen property of the Popup will be true only when the trigger condition is true. Once the trigger condition becomes false the IsOpen property will be reset to its default value of false. Why? Because this is the way triggers work in WPF.

Remember that XAML is a *markup* language and even if you actually can implement certain things in pure XAML it doesn't mean that you should always do this.

A programming language like C# is more concise and expressive than XAML and should generally be used to implement any behaviour in your application.

This is an example where it would be much easier to handle the mouse events programmatically and explicitly set the IsOpen property of the Popup to true/false instead of trying to use XAML triggers.

Comment: Is there any notion to why the triggers work like this? Btw. I think I will do it in the view model, but I was curious if it could be done with XAML triggers.

Comment: "The properties changed by triggers are automatically reset to their previous value when the triggered condition is no longer satisfied": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger(v=vs.110).aspx. This is the expected behaviour. Consider for example that you apply an IsMouseOver trigger to an element. Then you would not want this brush to stick around when the mouse leaves. This would be very strange.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger is fire each time `IsMouseOver` property change. If the value is true it will trigger changes you set in `Trigger` else it will send back to initial state.

The right way would be to do it by event call, I don't know if the best event but like that you have an example:

```
<ListBox MouseEnter="ListBox_MouseEnter" x:Name="PART_ListBoxBonusTargets" Height="200"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Targets}" />

private void ListBox_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        e.Handled = true;
        PART_PopupListBoxBonusTargets.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Comment: I know I can do it if I wire up the `MouseEnter` event. If nothing else helps I'd even go so far to make a property in the viewmodel. I am however curious about why the trigger would cause a change to the view when its condition is not met. You said "send back to initial state". Why does it do that?

Comment: To clarify, what is the reasoning behind this behaviour? Is it to avoid someone from forgetting to trigger on the `false` case or has it some deeper background I'm no aware of?

Comment: A Trigger is triggered each time the property which is link to is "updated".          So when you leave the `ListBox` your `IsMouseOver` property is updated to false since it's an dependency property your ui thread check if there is something to update and in your case it will redo the check of the `Trigger` you define

Comment: It's more about gaining more control mechanic in view, it improve the use of templates and binding which allows to bypass controls code